# Why are type checks and type casts considered poor style in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, casting

In the book *Programming in Scala, 2nd ed.*, the authors write that "writing type tests and casts is rather verbose in Scala. That’s intentional, because it is not encouraged practice.
You are usually better off using a pattern match with a typed pattern." Elsewhere they repeat that using those constructs is "poor style".

I totally agree that the pattern matching syntax of Scala is much nicer, but isn't it basically syntactic sugar for type checks and type casts? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It isn't always sugar for type checks, it can also cover null checks, switch, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is sugar, but it's very helpful sugar.  You can get into real trouble with type casts by

- Not checking `isInstanceOf` before calling `asInstanceOf`
- Forgetting that generics don't know their argument type with `isInstanceOf`
- Not covering all cases for the type being passed

Pattern matching handles all this for you correctly: you only get an instance if there actually is one, it warns on generics, and warns if you have an incomplete match.  Thus, where type tests and casts are error-prone, pattern matching is robust and encourages good design.